# Is it ok to remove pork and eat food?

Tags: halal-haram, pork

Asalaam alaikum,

I went to Subway today and got a Steak and spicy chorizo sandwich. I was recommended it by a muslim friend, and when i asked him if spicy chorizo was halal, he said it was just meat.

However, once I got back to my desk and had a bite, I quickly googled it - just to double check and to my surprise, I learnt spicy chorizo is actually pork..

I then removed the spicy chorizo and carried on eating half of the sandwhich, but then I thought this is wrong and now feel extremely guilty. You surely still can't eat something which had pork in it before?

My two questions for the forum:

1.) Are you able to eat food which had pork in it (pork was removed).
2.) what do I have to do to in order to attempt to gain forgiveness for eating pork?

Thanks for your time, I look forward to hearing from you.

Comment: In Islam, all actions are based on intention (niyah). Hence, w.r.t #2, you took a bite not knowing it was pork i.e unintentionally  ...  Allah is Most Merciful and inshallah  no sin will be assigned to you for that action. Ameen.

Answer (score 4):

Pork is unclean ([najis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Najis)) and najis is transferred through wetness:

> A thing (such as your hand, clothes, etc.) becomes najis only when it comes in contact with a najis thing with wetness that can be transferred and that can be felt when touched. -- Maulana Sadiq Hasan ([pdf](http://panjtan.org.au/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/Fiqh-Lecture-24-of-2003.pdf))

It's probable that the pork-removed sandwich remains najis, and shouldn't be eaten.  [Islam Q&A](https://islamqa.info/en/114129) recommend:

> The pig is haraam and najis (impure)... If some parts of its meat or fat is found in bread, food or medicine, it is haraam to consume it at all.

There's online fatawa which talk about the number of times a utensil ([AskImam.org](http://askimam.org/public/question_detail/16030), [Halal Times](http://www.halaltimes.com/can-muslim-eat-halal-food-dish-cooked-pan-already-used-pork-cooking/)), a dish or cloth ([IslamWeb.org](http://islamweb.org/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=242908)), or a body part ([Shafiifiqh.com](http://islamqa.org/shafii/shafiifiqh/29981), [Islam Q&A](https://islamqa.info/en/20843)) should be washed after being contaminated by pork.  These indicate that one should have a high level of caution in relation to pork.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't eat it - you have to be wary of contamination. Plus your Muslim friend isn't very knowledgable at all because the steak wouldn't be halal either! It is VERY important to eat food that is halal and tayyib so I suggest you educate yourself and your friend immediately.

This link is a guide for "Muslims in Britain" for Muslims and non Muslims but applicable to any country in general. Section linked is halal food:
http://guide.muslimsinbritain.org/guide8.html#8.2